# Is there such a thing as "hypertopology" (analogous to the hyperreals)?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

The [hyperreal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) number system adds infinities and infinitesimals, allowing Calculus to be done using these things instead of limits (sort of like when calculus was originally invented, but with rigor).This got me thinking, could this be done with topology to create hypertopology (an equivalent but perhaps more intuitive way of doing topology)?

It should be able to translate, since hyperreals can be represented as ultrafilters of reals. Hypertopology would involve ultrafilters of the points of the topology presumably.

To define the topology, I presume you would define when two points of the hypertopology are infinitesimally close. To convert a metric space into a topology, you would simply define two hypertopology points as close whenever their distance is infinitesimal (again, ultrafilters can be applied point wise.)

Has this ever been studied? What axioms would hypertopology "closeness" need to follow to be equivalent to regular topology? Is there an axiomatic approach (not requiring the ultrafilters (the hyperreals have an axiomatic basis))?

Comment: Chapter 2 of Albeverio's *Nonstandard methods in stochastic analysis and mathematical physics* in on topology and linear spaces in the context of nonstandard analysis.

Comment: Since any hyperreal field is an orderded field, it can be equipped with the order topology.

Comment: @nombre I'm not talking about topologies on hyperstuff. I'm talking about using the hyperversion of something to define its topology.

Comment: Oh my bad. You want to find an easy intuitive way to define an open set of reals using its hyperreal counterpart? Then what about "a set $A$ of real numbers is open if there is an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ such that for all $x \in \ ^*A$, $B(x,\varepsilon) \subset \ ^*A$"?

Comment: @nombre I want to generalize this beyond the reals to as much topology as possible. As hyperreals replaced limits with infinitesimals, hypertopology should replace neighborhood arguments with infinitely close point arguments.

Comment: Isn't this the idea of what I just suggested? Note that this is the same as "for all $x \in \ ^*A$ and infinitesimal $\varepsilon$, $x+\varepsilon \in \ ^*A$"

Comment: @nombre Again, that is only for topology on reals. Do you know how this would work for topologies that don't come with metrics?

Comment: Ok. Maybe you will get other answers if you specify whether you are looking for a whole new approach and context (similar to IST for instance) or if you want to work in the context of ultrapowers.

Comment: Non-standard topology normally starts with a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ and forms a non-standard extension ${^*X}$, so you have the topology on $X$ to begin with. However, you can then use the extension to prove things about $X$ just as you can use the hyperreals to prove things about $\Bbb R$. [This PDF](http://library.iugaza.edu.ps/thesis/98380.pdf) of an M.Sc. thesis at the Islamic Univ. of Gaza gives an introduction to the notions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-standard topology normally starts with a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ and forms a non-standard extension ${^*X}$, so you have the topology on $X$ to begin with. However, you can then use the extension to prove things about $X$ just as you can use the hyperreals to prove things about $\Bbb R$. [This PDF](http://library.iugaza.edu.ps/thesis/98380.pdf) of an M.Sc. thesis at the Islamic University of Gaza gives an introduction to the notions.

Comment: The source you mentioned is not accessible.  It may be useful to provide a more standard source, such as Goldblatt's book on the hyperreals.

Answer (score 2):

As PyRulez suggested, the hyperreals are useful in clarifying certain topological concepts. For example, compactness of $X$ can be characterized by saying that every point of ${}^\ast\! X$ is infinitely close to a standard point of $X$. Using this characterisation dramatically shortens proofs of key results, such as compactness of a product of compact spaces.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there an axiomatic approach (not requiring the ultrafilters (the hyperreals have an axiomatic basis))?"

We recently developed such an approach.  It requires no ultrafilters as requested, and indeed is able to handle the nonstandard definition of compactness (every point is infinitely close to a standard point).  See [this publication](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#23c) and [https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/spot.html](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html) for an introduction.